# Find all the occurences of a substring inside a string and change the substrings with the values of a dictionnary using python

Tags: python, dictionary, substring

I can't share the data I am work with , so this is just an example.

I have a dictionnary that contains the measure names to be changed:

```
dict_A = {time1 : time_of_the_call, time 12 : duration_of_the_call , time17 : when_the_call_ended, ... }
```

I need to find the key of the dictionnary A inside a string of another dictionnary B. Dictionnary B contains strings of formulas/expression.

```
dict_B = {expression : SUM(TABLE1['time1'],TABLE['time12']+TABLE['time17']), ....}
```

I tried with regex but I don't have the desired output. I think as soon as it finds time1 it stops to check the other keys.

```
ouput : {expression : SUM(TABLE1['time_of_the_call'],TABLE['time_of_the_call']+TABLE['time_of_the_call'])
```

```
desired output : {expression : SUM(TABLE1['time_of_the_call'],TABLE['duration_of_the_call']+TABLE['when_the_call_ended'])
```

How could I do this in PYTHON ? Dictionary B contains about 250 expressions and they differ a lot in formulas. Dictionary A contains around 350 measures names that need to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`re.sub()`](https://lzone.de/examples/Python%20re.sub)

```py
for key, value in dict_A.items():
    for expression, formula in dict_B.items():
        dict_B[expression] = re.sub(r"\['" + key + r"\']", r"['" + value + r"']", formula)
print(dict_B)
```

---

```
{'expression': "SUM(TABLE1['time_of_the_call'],TABLE['duration_of_the_call']+TABLE['when_the_call_ended'])"}
```